# Android: How to create the Google Plus login animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-layout, authentication, google-plus

Does anyone know how to create a similar animation to the login animation used in the Google Plus Android app?

Is there something similar in the Android SDK that I can use? Or should I just build it from scratch? I'm interested especially in the fact that the UI behind the modal animation is dimmed and disabled.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Some example or a video or at least a screenshot would really help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you taking about that progress dialog spinning thingy that says "signing in"? That's not a custom animation at all, it's a common widget.

Here's the code:

```
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
        progressDialog.show();
        //... complete sign in...then
        progressDialog.dismiss();
```

A ProgressDialog done this way, automatically takes care of dimming/blurring the background. You should really read about dialogs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, I admit I was lazy, I should have looked into the available dialogs. I'm just starting Android development and there is just too much info to take in at once.

Answer (score 1):

To show the progression with an animated progress bar:

1- Initialize the `ProgressDialog` with the class constructor, `ProgressDialog(Context)`.
Set the progress style to `"STYLE_HORIZONTAL"` with `setProgressStyle(int`) and set any other properties, such as the message.

2- When you're ready to show the dialog, call show() or return the `ProgressDialog` from the onCreateDialog(int) callback.

3- You can increment the amount of progress displayed in the bar by calling either `setProgress(int)` with a value for the total percentage completed so far or `incrementProgressBy(int)` with an incremental value to add to the total percentage completed so far.

For example, your setup might look like this:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

The setup is simple. Most of the code needed to create a progress dialog is actually involved in the process that updates it. You might find that it's necessary to create a second thread in your application for this work and then report the progress back to the Activity's UI thread with a Handler object. If you're not familiar with using additional threads with a Handler, see the example Activity below that uses a second thread to increment a progress dialog managed by the Activity.

Comment: Thanks. That's valuable info.